# Predicate to retrieve the last N unique names from CoreData.

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a core data entity that looks like this:

```
name: String
creationDate: Date
```

I would like to retrieve the last 5 unique names when ordered in descending order by creation date. What is the most efficient way to query this data from CoreData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both these solutions are efficient depending on the situation.

If you do not have memory constraints (i.e. not too many records) you could fetch all sorted by date, use KVC to filter and take the top n records.

```
(allItems as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfSets.name")
```

If you like to fetch this directly from the store, you have to drop back to `NSDictionaryResultType` for your fetch request. Something like

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Item")
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType
request.returnsDistinctResults = true
let entity = NSEntityDescription(name: "Item", inManagedObjectContext: context)
let description = entity.propertiesByName["name"]
request.propertiesToFetch = [description!]
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
request.fetchLimit = 5
```

Comment: After testing this out a bit more, it is not selecting unique `name`s. It is only selecting unique `Item`s. Is there a way to fix this?